# How to exclude DataArray's NaN values from computation

Tags: python, python-xarray

I need to multiply a DataArray to a costant. Before the operation my DataArray looks like as below:

```
<xarray.DataArray (band: 1, y: 7961, x: 7851)>
[62501811 values with dtype=uint16]
Coordinates:
  * band         (band) int64 1
  * x            (x) float64 2.28e+05 2.28e+05 2.281e+05 ... 4.635e+05 4.635e+05
  * y            (y) float64 4.585e+06 4.585e+06 ... 4.346e+06 4.346e+06
    spatial_ref  int64 0
Attributes:
    _FillValue:    0.0
    scale_factor:  1.0
    add_offset:    0.0
```

After:

```
<xarray.DataArray (band: 1, y: 7961, x: 7851)>
array([[[-62.59149, -62.59149, -62.59149, ..., -62.59149, -62.59149,
         -62.59149],
        [-62.59149, -62.59149, -62.59149, ..., -62.59149, -62.59149,
         -62.59149],
        [-62.59149, -62.59149, -62.59149, ..., -62.59149, -62.59149,
         -62.59149],
        ...,
        [-62.59149, -62.59149, -62.59149, ..., -62.59149, -62.59149,
         -62.59149],
        [-62.59149, -62.59149, -62.59149, ..., -62.59149, -62.59149,
         -62.59149],
        [-62.59149, -62.59149, -62.59149, ..., -62.59149, -62.59149,
         -62.59149]]])
Coordinates:
  * band         (band) int64 1
  * x            (x) float64 2.28e+05 2.28e+05 2.281e+05 ... 4.635e+05 4.635e+05
  * y            (y) float64 4.585e+06 4.585e+06 ... 4.346e+06 4.346e+06
    spatial_ref  int64 0
```

I want that NaNs remain NaNs after the operation. Some indication about it?

Comment: Integer typed  numpy arrays can’t have nans, so there’s no way your original data had any. It seems you have a FillValue of 0. If this is purely a multiplication by a scalar, you could use `result = result.where(result != 0)` to introduce nans

Comment: alternatively you could do `result = result.where(original != 0)` to introduce nans into your final wherever there were 0 values in the original

Comment: Your last comment is more useful than first for me. If you add it as answer I can vote you. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy's integer types (e.g. `int8, int16, int32, int64`, and the unsigned `uint` equivalents) do not have a "NaN" value, and so cannot contain NaNs. Therefore, when xarray reads in a netCDF with integer data type and a FillValue, it does not replace values which are equal to the FillValue with NaNs.

In order to introduce NaNs to your data, you will need to cast the data as a float type. Depending on your values, this may result in a loss of precision or an expansion of the data size. Simply casting an int16 as a `float` (default `float64`) will result in the size of your data increasing by a factor of 4!

Once you do this, you can mask the data using [`xr.where`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.where.html) (or the [`DataArray`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.where.html)/[`Dataset`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.where.html) equivalents):

```py
da = da.where(da != da._FillValue)
```

You can also do this after downstream processing if your results are still the same shape and your operations have been element-wise, e.g.:

```py
result = result.where(da != da._FillValue)
```